# Why Safari does not save Cookie in response to storage?

Tags: node.js, cookies, safari

I have nodeJS website that sends cookie back to browser in response.
I am testing in local network development environment where the website is started at 192.168.1.12.
At the following is the screenshot of Safari console where I can see the cookie is in the response
[image]

However, in Safari's cookie storage tab the cookie is not presented
[image]

So my question is: Why Safari does not take the cookie returned in the response?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is Safari cached data. After clearing Safari browser historical data, the problem is resolved and cookie is saved into storage after refreshing the page.